# System without ground state is not real in nature?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, schroedinger-equation, potential, unitarity

We know that Coulomb force is real phenomena in nature and with Coulomb potential $V(x) \thicksim -\frac{1}{|x|}$ lowest energy is bounded in hydrogen atom. But it's mathematically clear that if Coulomb potential is replaced with strange potential $V(x) \thicksim -\frac{1}{|x|^ {10}}$ the ground state energy cannot be bounded from below and system is not stable/possible in quantum mechanical sense. So,  is the following implication true? $$\text{Force is not possible in QM   }\rightarrow \text{   Force is not real in nature}$$

Comment: Why does your other potential not have a well-defined ground state?  Do you have a proof that the bound eigenstates of this potential form a continuum or something?

Comment: That potential is so singular that no uncertainity principle generated kinetic energy can control it, so $E_0 \rightarrow -\infty$.

Comment: Why?  I contend that that is not likely to be true.

Comment: Well, I don't have actual  proof right now but it is plain simple that with some $p>1$ the potential $V(x) \thicksim -1/|x|^p$ becomes too singular. Hope you not disagree :)

Comment: Too singular for what?  You're just throwing buzzwords together.

Comment: How can something be "too singular"? Whether it's $1/x$ or $1/x^{10}$, it's still undefined at $x=0$ and not for $x=\epsilon$ for some small value.

Comment: What I mean is that with every state $\psi$ the expression $<E_{kin}>+<V> \text{ } \rightarrow -\infty$, and that's why there can be no ground state.

Comment: Relevant publication from 1931: http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.38.120 . He solves the quantum mechanical states of the inverse cube central force. In short, I think your question may be founded on a misunderstanding.

Comment: @dmckee. My implication arrow was only to right direction since I'm sure that potentials like $\thicksim -1/|x|^p$ when $p<1$ are bounded from below as they are weaker that Coulomb potential, BUT there are unphysical examples amoung them, e.g. what the hell is the force if $p=\pi /8$ ...

Comment: Just for completeness the inverse cube force rule has apparently been solved in 1D, too: http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.2165248. There is no mathematical problem with defining exponentiation to a irrational power. Indeed $e$ itself is irrational so the natural exponential is an example of that. I rather down that particular case has been solved, but at this point I think it is on you to *show* that there is a problem.

Comment: Difficult to imagine nature as 1D. My only question was that if some force is not possible in QM does that mean that force is not real in nature?

Comment: Self-adjointness is surely more an issue here from the QM point of view than the existence of a ground state. The results are really dimension dependent, but in three dimensions, for potentials of this type, a sufficient condition is square integrability around the origin. So up to $\lvert x\rvert^{-3/2}$ excluded you have self-adjointness. For more negative powers, that is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another reason why such a potential needs further attention. The point is that the system must have a unitary time evolution which is generated by a self-adjoint Hamiltonian. Thus one has to verify that $H={-{(∂/∂_{\bf{x}})}^2}/(2m)+V(x)$ defined on a suitable dense domain (for instance smooth square integrable functions vanishing in a neighbourhood of $0$) has a self-adjoint extension. There can be more than one in which case the physics should lead to the right choice. In case $V(x)$ is non-negative one can start from the associated quadratic form (Friedrichs extension) to obtain a self-adjoint operator.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrichs_extension
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_of_symmetric_operators

Comment: Agreed. Self-adjointness must be checked before start utilizing Strange potentials in QM. It seems to be tricky mathematical problem even for Hamiltonian with Coulomb potential.

Comment: Relevant literature for self-adjointness questions are Kato's "Linear Operators" and Reed and Simon "Methods of Modern Nathematical Physics II". There most known cases of Schrödinger operators are covered.

Answer (score 0):

> the ground state energy cannot be bounded from below and system is not stable/possible in quantum mechanical sense.

in fact, the system could radiate an infinite amount of energy (photons) which for example would make a fundamental law such as the conservation of energy useless.

> So, is the following implication true?
>   Force is not possible in QM → Force is not real in nature

no, that is not necessarily true.

Keep in mind that the theory of Quantum Mechanics is our description of nature, it's not that nature has to follow the description we come up with. If at some point we observe an effect which can't be described by Quantum Mechanics (and we are sure that there are no mistakes made in the observation) then we will have to extend / generalize it.

For example, the fact that in Newtonian mechanics all inertial frames share the same universal time does not imply that this is actually what is happening in nature (which it isn't in fact).

Comment: Agreed. My question was hastily stated and maybe too philosofical; basic QM is just a theory that expains some data, not theory of everything.